# Click does not come after CSS3 transformation

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have the problem under Chrome/Safari browsers. After applying CSS3 transformation I don't receive **mouseup** and **click** events (under IE9/10 it work very well).

This is my not working sample:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(".box").mousedown(function (e) {
        $(this).addClass('transform');
    });

    $(".box").mouseup(function (e) {
        $(this).removeClass('transform');
    });

    $(".box").click(function (e) {
        alert("Click"); // Not worked under Chrome/Safari !
    });
</script>

<div class="box"></div>
```

and CSS3 style:

```
.box {
    background-color:#f00;
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
}

.transform {
    transform-origin: 0% 50%;
    transform: rotateY(10deg);
    -ms-transform-origin: 0% 50%;
    -ms-transform: rotateY(10deg);
    -webkit-transform-origin: 0% 50%;
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(10deg);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you needed to set `position:absolute`:

```
.transform {
    transform-origin: 0% 50%;
    transform: rotateY(30deg);
    -ms-transform-origin: 0% 50%;
    -ms-transform: rotateY(30deg);
    -webkit-transform-origin: 0% 50% 0px;
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(-31deg);
}​
```

[Check this Demo UPDATED 2](http://jsfiddle.net/54RZL/10/)

You can check this links about transformation

- [Mozilla doc about Transform](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/transform)
- [Transform-origin](http://css-infos.net/property/-webkit-transform-origin)

Comment: Thank you but I see difference betwean rotate (2D) and rotateX/Y (3D). My idea was use 3D transformation.

Comment: Ok, I remove unnecessary colons and received the same result as I described in my question.

Comment: Thank you very much. Your example worked now. As I understood the solution is to use position: absolute?

Comment: In the latest Chrome mouseup and click do not fire if you click on right corner of the box (which disappears on mousedown)

Answer (score 2):

This is a browser bug with webkit. The clicks will work fine as long as you are very careful to cancel out any z-transform (correctly - simpler is better).

Firefox and IE both will handle the clicks despite their z-transform.

The position:absolute may work for some, but it is an inappropriate solution to a browser failure.

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple reasons this may happen. One of them, as mentioned, is that the position:absolute should be set on a parent somewhere.

However, there is also currenty a bug in webkit (and likely the other browsers) where a transformZ value is randomly computed for a transformed face. The solution is hence to apply:

```
-webkit-transform:translateZ(0px);
-moz-transform:translateZ(0px);
transform:translateZ(0px);
```

to the element which is giving you interactivity problems. This worked for me on a div element which was transformed with a bunch of nested child elements, and would intermittently give me click feedback at different angles. I know this is what is happening, because I was able to 'fix' the issue by moving one of the child elements over beyond the edge of the parent element, meaning that the parent element was invisibly obscuring the child element.

However it should be mentioned this fix also appeared to solve a bunch of other problems with the Z-depth of subsequent child elements, which really should not have existed in the first place. This suggests a simple looping render bug, meaning this 'fix' may break with future updates of browsers as the devs tweak the render routines.